# Labview case event

Tags: labview

I am running a VI with a calibration part that is currently executing once at the start of the program. To control it instead by an OK button on the front panel, I replaced the case structure by an event structure. However, the VI now shows an error saying that the array I am converting to a variant is not initialized when I click on the OK button. Any hints?

[image: Case structure]

The false case just outputs an array made of the two single elements in the input

[image: Event structure]

Comment: The problem is you think that i==1 is the first call (init). Please connect i == 0 and check if the error shows up? If so please add some info so I can help.

Comment: My gut feeling is that there is some logic that fails in front of the event loop, passing an uninitialized array to the event structure when it starts waiting for the event. Event structures does not wait for events before the connected wires passes their data to the loop, if that's what you were suspecting.

Comment: I agree - please post the rest of your code left of the Event structure so we can help you.

Comment: Person asking this question has declined to provide further updates to help community answer the question.